# Can someone explain the logic here?

Tags: python

So I was doing some practice on creating a python class to convert int to roman numerals, my solution works but it would be an extremely long code to convert all possible numbers so I checked the solution on the page (code below) which obviously works but I don't understand the logic in the for loop, could someone please explain it?

```
class py_solution:
    def int_to_Roman(self, num):
        val = [
            1000, 900, 500, 400,
            100, 90, 50, 40,
            10, 9, 5, 4,
            1
            ]
        syb = [
            "M", "CM", "D", "CD",
            "C", "XC", "L", "XL",
            "X", "IX", "V", "IV",
            "I"
            ]
        roman_num = ''
        i = 0
        while  num > 0:
            for _ in range(num // val[i]):
                roman_num += syb[i]
                num -= val[i]  
            i += 1
        return roman_num


print(py_solution().int_to_Roman(0))
print(py_solution().int_to_Roman(1400))
```

Comment: Lets take the example of the `1400` input. First `while` loop run, the for loop will complete `1400//1000` (=1) time. To the roman numeral string (currently `''`), it adds the letter associated with the first `syb` value, then subtracts the `val` from `num`.  So after the first `while` loop we have completed the for loop once and have `num=400`, `roman_num='M'`.  Walk through manually what the rest of the loops are and you will see how it works

Comment: It totally makes sense now! Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to notice the // operator, which is floor division.

In the case of int_to_Roman(0) the program doesn't not get into the while nor for because num is not greater than 0.

In the second case, int_to_Roman(1400), the range is 1. Because 1400/1000 is 1.

Then roman_num would be M and num = 400 (1400-1000).
Now the value of i is 1.
Since num is greater than 0, we enter the for loop again. This time val[1] is 900, thus the result of 400 // 900 is 0, nothing to do, go to next step.

```
Now i=2 and val[2] is 500, again the range is 0. Next step. 
i=3, val[3] is 400, now the range is 1 (400 // 400). 
roman_num is M + CD and num = 0.
```

End of the while and the returned value is MCD.

Answer (score 0):

What specifically do you not understand? Try commenting what each line is doing, e.g.:

```
i = 0
while  num > 0:
    for _ in range(num // val[i]): # Loop the number of times current value divides num
        roman_num += syb[i]        # Add the current symbol to the answer
        num -= val[i]              # Subtract current value from number
    i += 1                         # Go to the next value/symbol
```

This could be simplified:

```
i = 0
while num > 0:
    x = num // val[i]
    num -= val[i]*x
    roman_num += syb[i]*x          # Add x times the current symbol
    i += 1
```

Note:

```
num -= val[i]*x   # x = num // val[i]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
num %= val[i]     # The remainder (modulus)
```

The `while` loop isn't really doing anything because `num` will always be `0` for the last value of `1`, so you can just loop over the indexes of value and symbol:

```
for i in range(len(val)):
    x = num // val[i]
    num %= val[i]
    roman_num += syb[i]*x
```

Note:

```
x = num // val[i]
num %= val[i]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
x, num = divmod(num, val[i])
```

Looping over an index is considered not very pythonic, when you can iterate directly over the values and symbols:

```
for v, s in zip(val, syb):
    x, num = divmod(num, v)
    roman_num += s*x
```

Note: the value and symbols have to be in descending order for either of these loops to work.